# Is it possible to set `-fexceptions` flag for building yaml-cpp using CMake

Tags: cmake, yaml-cpp

I am trying to integrate libyaml-cpp to a project that uses CMake. I added the yaml-cpp using `add_subdirectory(yaml-cpp)`, to the CMakefile. However my project uses the following flag `-fno-exceptions` for the gcc compiler settings. This flag issues the following error when building `yaml-cpp` :

```
/yaml-cpp/include/yaml-cpp/node/impl.h:60:35: error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable throw InvalidNode(m_invalidKey);
```

So, the solution is to enable the `-fexceptions` flag. But I want to enable this only for the `yaml-cpp` build and not the rest of the project.

I am new to `Cmake` and `yaml-cpp`. Is there a way to set this flag `-fexceptions` in the Cmakefile (for `yaml-cpp`), so that build goes through.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the yaml-cpp code in the GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp), and assuming you are building on a Unix system, the compilation options (flags) for the `yaml-cpp` target are applied in the CMake file [here](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/blob/b650bc8287ac92a5d93f94f20911fc1d7b4df94a/CMakeLists.txt#L87), at the [`target_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html) call. Just add the `-fexceptions` flag to that call, for the `not-msvc` case:

**yaml-cpp/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
...
target_compile_options(yaml-cpp
  PRIVATE
    # Add -fexceptions to this line.
    $<${not-msvc}:-Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Weffc++ -Wno-long-long -fexceptions>
    $<${not-msvc}:-pedantic -pedantic-errors>

    $<$<AND:${backport-msvc-runtime},${msvc-rt-mtd-static}>:-MTd>
    $<$<AND:${backport-msvc-runtime},${msvc-rt-mt-static}>:-MT>
    $<$<AND:${backport-msvc-runtime},${msvc-rt-mtd-dll}>:-MDd>
    $<$<AND:${backport-msvc-runtime},${msvc-rt-mt-dll}>:-MD>

    # /wd4127 = disable warning C4127 "conditional expression is constant"
    # http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t66728h.aspx
    # /wd4355 = disable warning C4355 "'this' : used in base member initializer list
    # http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c594ae3.aspx
    $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/W3 /wd4127 /wd4355>)
```